# How to detect what is changing my variable?

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code where `data` is a list of purchasable items and `user` contains all the items purchased from that list by a user. `itemid` is the item we want to look up and `itemfeat` is the list of that item features. `calcfeat` will add the item features to the list of purchases of the user only if this is not present yet, otherwise it will return a message.

`checkpurchases` will delete the entire object containing the feature and its value in case the latter is already `0`, if not then it will only subtract by one. This is where I have an issue. The function is supposed to subtract and change the value in `user.purchases` only, but it also changes it in `data` which I don't want.

```js
var data = 
  [ { id: 'a5', cost: 250, feats: null, css: '' } 
  , { id: 'a6', cost: 350, feats: [ { id: 'size', value: 1} ] } 
  , { id: 'a7', cost: 150, feats: null, css: ''}  
  ];

var itemid   = 'a6';
var itemfeat = data.filter(d =>
  d.id === itemid && d.feats).reduce((acc, d) => 
    [...acc, ...d.feats], []);

var user = { userid: '45', username: 'john', purchases: [{ id: 'size', value: 1 }]};

calcfeat = function(itemfeat) {
  itemfeat.forEach(e => {
    let obj = user.purchases.find(a => a.id === e.id);

    if (obj) {
      console.log('item is still present');
    } else {
      user.purchases.push(e);
    }
  });
}

checkpurchases = function() {
  if (user.purchases.length != 0) {
    user.purchases.map(a => {
      if (a.value == 0) {
        var nopurchase = user.purchases.filter((b) => {
          return b.id != a.id;
        });

        user.purchases = nopurchase;

      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user.purchases) 
                  + '                      before check' 
                  + JSON.stringify(data) 
                  + '========================================');
        a.value = a.value - 1; //this will change [{"id":"size","value":1}] to [{"id":"size","value":0}] inside user.purchases but also in data which I dont intend
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user.purchases) 
                  + '                      after check' 
                  + JSON.stringify(data) 
                  + '========================================');
      }
    });
  }
}

calcfeat(itemfeat);
checkpurchases();
```

Unfortunately I can't reproduce the error here, seems like something else in my environment is causing it which is weird because I have included here all the instances where `data` is involved but still, I get that issue so I wonder if there is a way to determine exactly what is changing the value inside `data`.

I wrapped `a.turns= a.turns - 1;` around console logs and according to that its this bit what is changing it but that doesn't make any sense since that should only affect the value inside user.purchases since there is no references to `data` whatsoever.

Comment: Definitely can't repro this here, so your problem is somewhere else. Suspect it might be that you are accessing `data` by reference somewhere, so when you update the reference, you also update it in `data`. Also a side note, this is very hard to read when all the variables are named after single letters. Storage is cheap, consider taking advantage of meaningfully-named vars.

Comment: First, why are you using map to do the same thing as a foreach? If you aren't returning anything you should just use a for each instead.

Comment: I tried forEach as well and I got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. If you add an object to an array, both the array element and the original variable point to the same object in memory.

To set 'a' to a new object, you can use the spread operator `...` to copy the existing properties and only provide a value for properties you want to change:

```js
// old way changes the object pointed to by 'a', and anywhere else
// that has a reference to the same object will see the update
//   a.value = a.value - 1

// new way creates a new object with a changed value property, anywhere
// else will reference the original object with an unchanged value proprety
a = {...a, value: a.value - 1}
```

```js
var data = 
  [ { id: 'a5', cost: 250, feats: null, css: '' } 
  , { id: 'a6', cost: 350, feats: [ { id: 'size', value: 1} ] } 
  , { id: 'a7', cost: 150, feats: null, css: ''}  
  ];

var itemid   = 'a6';
var itemfeat = data.filter(d =>
  d.id === itemid && d.feats).reduce((acc, d) => 
    [...acc, ...d.feats], []);

var user = { userid: '45', username: 'john', purchases: [{ id: 'size', value: 1 }]};

calcfeat = function(itemfeat) {
  itemfeat.forEach(e => {
    let obj = user.purchases.find(a => a.id === e.id);

    if (obj) {
      console.log('item is still present');
    } else {
      user.purchases.push(e);
    }
  });
}

checkpurchases = function() {
  if (user.purchases.length != 0) {
    user.purchases.map(a => {
      if (a.value == 0) {
        var nopurchase = user.purchases.filter((b) => {
          return b.id != a.id;
        });

        user.purchases = nopurchase;

      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user.purchases) 
                  + '                      before check' 
                  + JSON.stringify(data) 
                  + '========================================');
        a = {...a, value: a.value - 1} // create a new object
        // a.value = a.value - 1; //this will change [{"id":"size","value":1}] to [{"id":"size","value":0}] inside user.purchases but also in data which I dont intend
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user.purchases) 
                  + '                      after check' 
                  + JSON.stringify(data) 
                  + '========================================');
      }
    });
  }
}

calcfeat(itemfeat);
checkpurchases();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The map() method is a copying method. It does not alter this. However, the function provided as callbackFn can mutate the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: How would missing declarations of global functions cause a problem like this?

Comment: I tried forEach as well but with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, I don't see any direct manipulation of the data array within the checkpurchases() function. However, there may be some indirect manipulation happening due to how the data array is being used in the itemid and itemfeat variables.

you can try to add a console log at the beginning of checkpurchases() to see what the value of data is before any changes are made.

Comment: I already did that. You can see it in action at the snippet I posted. Right before a.value = a.value - 1; and right after that. The value changes from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're experiencing is due to the fact that the itemfeat variable is being directly derived from the data variable. Therefore, when you modify the itemfeat array (which contains references to the objects in the data array), you're also modifying the original objects in the data array.

you can clone the objects in the data array before adding them to the itemfeat array. You can do this using the Object.assign() method, like so:

```js
const data = [
    { id: 'a5', cost: 250, feats: null, css: '' },
    { id: 'a6', cost: 350, feats: [{ id: 'size', value: 1 }] },
    { id: 'a7', cost: 150, feats: null, css: '' },
];

const itemid = 'a6';
var itemfeat = data
    .filter((d) => d.id === itemid && d.feats)
    .reduce((acc, d) => [...acc, Object.assign({}, d)], []);

const user = {
    userid: '45',
    username: 'john',
    purchases: [{ id: 'size', value: 1 }],
};

function calcfeat(itemfeat) {
    itemfeat.forEach((e) => {
        const obj = user.purchases.find((a) => a.id === e.id);

        if (obj) {
            console.log('item is still present');
        } else {
            user.purchases.push(e);
        }
    });
}

function checkpurchases() {
    if (user.purchases.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    user.purchases.forEach((a) => {
        if (a.value === 0) {
            user.purchases = user.purchases.filter((b) => b.id !== a.id);
        } else {
            console.log(
                `${JSON.stringify(user.purchases)} before check ${JSON.stringify(
                    data
                )} ========================================`
            );
            a.value -= 1;
            console.log(
                `${JSON.stringify(user.purchases)} after check ${JSON.stringify(
                    data
                )} ========================================`
            );
        }
    });
}

calcfeat(itemfeat);
checkpurchases();
```

This creates a new object for each item in itemfeat, which is a copy of the corresponding object in data, but without any references to the original object.

With this modification, the checkpurchases() function should no longer modify the original objects in the data array.

Comment: I also think setting a backup variable is the most practical way but I wanted to see if there are some other alternatives out there.

Answer (score 0):

> but that doesn't make any sense since that should only affect the value inside user.purchases

False.  When you have an array of objects, or set the property of one object to another, it is generally only a reference to the same underlying object.  Changing properties on this object will be reflected anywhere you attempt to use the underlying object:

```js
const a = { name: 'Alice', age: 31 }
const people = [ a ]
const c = people[0]
const contact = { person: c, phone: '712-865-7309' }
console.log('people[0] has age:', people[0].age)
a.age = 32
console.log('people[0] has age:', people[0].age, '(even though I did not touch people)')
console.log('c.age is ', c.age, 'because it references the same object')
console.log('contact.person.age is ', contact.person.age, 'because it also references the same object')
```

To help prevent mistakes like this, [Immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Immutable) programming has seen a resurgence.  There are libraries like
Immutable.js to help with this, and Javascript supports this via the [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method, which will make it so you truly cannot change the properties of an object, though it only applies to the actual object you freeze.  For instance if I freeze the object referenced by `a`, it cannot be changed.  But if I freeze the array containing `a`, the array can't be changed but the properties of `a` could be modified unless I freeze it as well:

```js
const a = { name: 'Alice', age: 31 }
Object.freeze(a)
const b = { name: 'Bob', age: 37 }
const people = [ a, b ]
Object.freeze(people)
console.log('people[0] has age:', people[0].age)
console.log('people[1] has age:', people[1].age)
a.age = 32 // this does not work, 'a' is frozen
b.age = 38 // this works, 'b' is not frozen
// people.push(a) // would throw an error trying to extend object
console.log('people[0] has age:', people[0].age)
console.log('people[1] has age:', people[1].age)
```

To find out exactly where it is being changed, you could I think use a
[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and throw an error
when the property is set.  That should show in the stack trace in the console where the code made the change:

```js
const setHandler = {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop === 'age') {
      throw new Error(`Attempting to set property ${prop} to ${value}`)
    }
    obj[prop] = value
  }
}

let a = { name: 'Alice', age: 31 }
a = new Proxy(a, setHandler)
const people = [ a ]
a.age = 32 //  uses proxy set, and throws error
```

Comment: This sounds interesting but I cant figure out how to use it on my actual code. Can you please adjust it to my code?